# react native firebase messaging click notification

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I received the notification from the sender, when I click the notification, app opened.

However, the notification return value does not call to the `onMessage()` function.

From the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/messaging/reference/messaging) , function `getInitialNotification()` is do what I need. But still not get any value from `onMessage()` when app opened.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification();
    firebase.messaging().onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...
    });
  }
```

Comment: try: `firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification().then(function(initialMessage) { console.log("Initial Message: ", initialMessage); })`

Comment: @Cherniv nice ! this is a correct answer, you should post to the answer ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/messaging/reference/messaging#getInitialNotification), `getInitialNotification` returns `Promise`, so you should use it like this:

```
firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification().then( ​initialMessage => {
   console.log("Initial Message: ", initialMessage); 
})
```

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/messaging/reference/messaging#getInitialNotification

Comment: I have a question, I'm developing two apps first of the user app and second to providers, in user app, I made some function to send order and saved into real-time database forecast and in the second app I just retrieve the data from DB with a listener to get the new order as a real-time without refreshing the app, SO I want to when I send an order from user app to firebase I want to display a notify in the second app? How to handle these